# how to add the JDBC API in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, java-module

I want establish a connection with a MySQL database. I downloaded JDBC from the official website of MySQL, and I added the jar file to my Eclipse IDE. However, when I tried to import java.sql package, it's still not accessible.
[image]

I don't know where is the problem. I watched some videos talk about database development perspective, shall I add it to my IDE? And do I need to download MySQL server?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you specify what do you want to do with the jdbc API in Eclipse?

Comment: to get connection with my database

Answer (score 2):

The JDBC API itself is included in Java. What you downloaded from the MySQL website is the MySQL Connector/J JDBC **driver**. You're using a modular project because `module-info.java` exists. If you want to use JDBC in a modular project, you will need to add `requires java.sql;` to your `module-info.java` to give it access to the `java.sql` module (which, among others, includes the `java.sql` and `javax.sql` packages).

If you want to use the MySQL classes directly, you will also need to add an appropriate `requires` directive for the MySQL library. However, in general you **should not** use JDBC driver classes directly, but only use the API from the `java.sql` and `javax.sql` packages.

Alternatively, delete the `module-info.java` to convert to a non-modular Java project.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. I did exactly like you and my Eclipse did not show any errors.

One guess would be that your Java modules get in the way and somehow prevent you from importing the classes. Can you try removing the `module-info.java` and disabling modules?

Also - very important, you have selected "jre" as your java runtime. Make sure you are using a JDK and not a simple JRE. The latter is used to run Java programs but the former is necessary when you develop them.

Comment: Since Java 9 the JRE no longer exists, and even if that weren't the case, JDBC is part of the JRE.